# How to validate date in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint Date Picker Control which is used to select a BirthDate . I want the birthdate to be atleast 16years older from the current date.

Can anyone guide me how to validate this using javascript? I have not used javascript much, Please guide me how to go about the validation process?

Comment: I would suggest you start here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using the library date.js:-

http://www.datejs.com/

This library adds a number of methods for working with date objects.

Without using an external library, the easiest way to compare a date of birth is over 16 is to convert the date to an epoch timestamp and then compare this against a timestamp of now minus 16 years.

Be aware that while most languages/platforms use timestamps in seconds, Javascript uses milliseconds, so when comparing against timestamps from external sources, you need to divide by a factor of 1000.

Comment: Just don't come back to SO when you sued over some underage user using your service just because he had 3 days to his 16th birthday on registering and you didn't bother to take leap years in account.

Comment: @Oleg Using a library you would convert the current date 16 years ago to your comparison timestamp rather than subtracting 16 years worth of seconds from a current timestamp. Without a library, yup, you must calculate leap days and leap seconds yourself, your note of caution is well placed!